# How do you apply a ID to a layer in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, css

I've purchased an AI file of UK postcodes; pictured are the layers it uses with each area named "Path"

[image]

I want these to be assigned an ID when I export as an SVG, so that I can apply database-driven data to the map.

I understand that it uses the layer name to apply ID, but even when I change the name from to a layer name, it doesn't apply an ID. It does add an ID to the parent layers.

I understand that it is likely something in the original AI file I have downloaded, but not sure how to change.

As an example, I delete all layers other than one postcode area - name that "show_id", export as SVG with Layer Names selected but it doesn't work. Added to pictures below

[image]

[image]

Comment: You really have no control over the exporter. It does what it does. Ok what kind of object is "post code areas?" (you can doubleclick on object in area not on names to show its dialog it says what it is)

Comment: Ok looks like things containing with "show_id" arent allowed change it then change back then it magically starts working

Comment: Still not working even if I rename it.

Comment: See,s to work for me. is "post code areas" a group or sublayer

Comment: "post code areas" is listed as neither a group of sublayer, but objects.  Think that may be my issue

Comment: Ahh it might be a compound object created in pathfinder would explain your thumbnail

Comment: Solved - I think; "Released to Layers" does the trick

Comment: You get 2 votes if you write that as an answer